# Cannot get array with useState and axios in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I have the database like this

```
[
  {
    "ymd": "2019-01-02",
    "dailyRevenue": 3464
  },
  {
    "ymd": "2019-01-03",
    "dailyRevenue": 3051
  },
  {
    "ymd": "2019-01-04",
    "dailyRevenue": 3495
  },
  {
    "ymd": "2019-01-05",
    "dailyRevenue": 4770
  },
  {
    "ymd": "2019-01-06",
    "dailyRevenue": 4907
  },
  {
    "ymd": "2019-01-07",
    "dailyRevenue": 2880
  },
]
```

And this is my code

```
export default function Dashboard() {
    const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/api/';
    const reLabel = ['2019-03-12', '2019-09-24'],       reData = [432,345];
    const [revenueHistoryLabel, setRevenueHistoryLabel] = useState([]);
    const [revenueHistoryData, setRevenueHistoryData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(API_URL + 'revenues').then((res) => {
            setRevenueHistoryLabel(
                ...revenueHistoryLabel,
                res.data.map((element) => element.ymd),
            );
            setRevenueHistoryData(
                ...revenueHistoryData,
                res.data.map((element) => element.dailyRevenue),
            );
        });
    }, []);
```

I tried to:

- retrieve ymd, then put it to revenueHistoryLabel as an array like ['2019-03-12', '2019-09-24']
- retrieve dailyRevenue, then put it to revenueHistoryData as an array like [432,345]

But after I called setRevenueHistoryLabel() and setRevenueHistoryData(), revenueHistoryLabel and revenueHistoryData were still empty arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
setRevenueHistoryLabel([
  ...revenuHistoryLabel,
  ...res.data.map((element) => element.ymd),
]);

setRevenueHistoryData([
  ...revenuHistoryData,
  ...res.data.map((element) => element.dailyRevenue),
]);
```

It seems that usage of `spread expression` in `setState` is wrong.

Comment: I tried. They're still empty arrays

Comment: @Khang-Truong First of all, try to check the value of `res.data`.

Comment: @Khang-Truong when you say they are empty, how are you checking ? having logs right after setting state ?

Comment: Hi. it works now. When I try your code and run console.log(revenueHistoryLabel[0]);  I can get the result that I want.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`axios.get("")` put your link here inspite of putting it into another variable

Sometimes this type of error occour, try and let me know.

Comment: No, that should work fine in either case ...

Comment: I tried. doesn't work

Comment: Great you find your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function Dashboard() {
    const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/api/';
    const reLabel = ['2019-03-12', '2019-09-24'],       reData = [432,345];
    const [revenueHistoryLabel, setRevenueHistoryLabel] = useState([]);
    const [revenueHistoryData, setRevenueHistoryData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(API_URL + 'revenues').then((res) => {
            setRevenueHistoryLabel([
                ...revenueHistoryLabel,
                ...res.data.map((element) => element.ymd),
            ]);
            setRevenueHistoryData([
                ...revenueHistoryData,
                ...res.data.map((element) => element.dailyRevenue),
            ]);
        });
    }, []);
```

Here is the ans. console.log shows array now. Thank you All

Comment: It should be as @ChanHyeok-Im answer .... `setRevenueHistoryLabel(...revenueHistoryLabel, ...res.data.map(...))` you should spread the mapped data too

Comment: I changed as you said. Thank you